# kube-apiserver startup failed with config error

Tags: kubernetes

I have one config file for kube-apiserver.

```
KUBE_APISERVER_OPTS="
--logtostderr=true
--v=4
--etcd-servers=https://172.16.0.2:2379,https://172.16.0.3:2379
--bind-address=172.16.0.2
--secure-port=6443
--advertise-address=172.16.0.2
--allow-privileged=true
--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/24
--enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota,NodeRestriction
--authorization-mode=RBAC,Node --enable-bootstrap-token-auth
--token-auth-file=/k8s/kubernetes/cfg/token.csv
--service-node-port-range=30000-50000
--tls-cert-file=/k8s/kubernetes/ssl/server.pem
--tls-private-key-file=/k8s/kubernetes/ssl/server-key.pem
--client-ca-file=/k8s/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
--service-account-key-file=/k8s/kubernetes/ssl/ca-key.pem
--etcd-cafile=/k8s/etcd/ssl/ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/k8s/etcd/ssl/server.pem
--etcd-keyfile=/k8s/etcd/ssl/server-key.pem"
```

Then I add system unit like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes API Server
Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/k8s/kubernetes/cfg/kube-apiserver
ExecStart=/k8s/kubernetes/bin/kube-apiserver $KUBE_APISERVER_OPTS
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I startup kube-apiserver, it shows me the hints with config error:

```
error: invalid authentication config: parse error on line 1, column 82: extraneous or missing " in quoted-field
```

Could you tell me where is my error, thanks much!
[error hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clRId.png)

Comment: Please, add the error directly to the question, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043)

Comment: sorry，the error message is :<error: invalid authentication config: parse error on line 1, column 82: extraneous or missing " in quoted-field>

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` environment files must be formatted correctly, which includes escaping the end of your lines if you wish to do multi line values:

```
APISERVER=" \
--arg-1=2 \
--arg-2=3 \
--arg-3=4 \
"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much anyway. i formatted the pattern of  environment file as you said, but the system show me  the same error message.what else prorable reason leads to that?